# How to pinpoint extremely slow / CPU hogging Eclipse startup times?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I need some Maven dependencies and stuff from my SBT project in my Eclipse RCP project so I used the [p2-maven-plugin](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin) to create an update site and install them into my workbench from there. Now, after installing them, I get some serious slowdowns. When installing, the step "Committing the provisioning operation" (83%) takes about 5 minutes and upon starting Eclipse (or running a plugin in an RCP style run configuration) takes about as long to start. During this time, I get 100% CPU usage and all memory I gave the workbench by the `-Xmx` setting in `eclipse.ini` is taken. I tried using `java` instead of `javaw` and started with `-verbose` but I don't get any output or log file written during this process.

How should I track down this slowdown?